# Sequential Loading fadeIn Effect with Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading, fadein

I recently came upon a website and I would like to replicate the loading fadeIn effect.

[You can see it here](http://work.lp-sf.com/index.php)

The loading and fading of the page is really nice because not everything fades in at the same time. It follows a sequential order I think.

This is the code that I found and assumed was the right code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".fade").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(100*i).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

I tried to copy this over to my site but it did nothing. I changed `".fade"` to another class specific to my site. I also couldn't see any errors on my page.

What's wrong? Why doesn't it work? Is there something else I need to change? What does `100*i` mean?

Comment: For each of your ".otherclass" elements.  Do they exist when the page has loaded? the "i" is the index position, so each "each" delays execution of the fade by "index position" multiplied by 100 (the total in milliseconds).  This makes each "each" happen 100 milliseconds after the previous "each" has started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fade something 'in' - it first must be invisible.
Make sure you add the following css:

```
.fade {
   display: none;   
}
```